# How do I change object's width on the fly and keep the object centered

Tags: css, width

How do I change object's width on the fly and keep the object centered?

What I have so far is:

```
function (theObject) {
  var origWidth = theObject.width();
  var newWidth = origWidth*2;  /* arbitrary example */

  theObject.width(newWidth);

  theObject.css('margin', '0 auto');
}
```

The last statement does not work. What am I doing wrong?

I really wish to **not** use transforms because of the "white space" problem.

BTW, the css style of theObject is pre-specified as

```
#theObject {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: #px;
   height: #px;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a simple demo where you reproduce the issue?

Comment: How old of browsers do you need to support? Does your "on the fly" only need to be when the client's browser is resized?

Comment: Jacob, here's the jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/1vxczhg3/23/

Comment: Tyler, it starts out centered with the above #theObject and I would like to squeeze in the width of theObject based on the window's width, i.e., when the window receives a resize Event. That is, if the window is resized to a width < theObject's width, then I need to decrease the width of theObject accordingly. As long as the window width is >= theObject's width, theObject stays the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You are really over-complexifying your solution. There is no need for JavaScript.

From the comments you said that you have these requirements:

1. When the window resizes, my element should resize
2. My element should only resize it is too big to display in the window

You should be able to accomplish this with 2 css properties. Width/height and max-width/max-height.

Use max to define the maximum size of your element and the width/height to define the actual size.

By using relative units you can make your width/height dynamically resize itself depending on the width/height of the parent or window.

The relative units I am familiar with include:

- %
- vh and vw
- em
- rem

% is the X% of the parent.
When assigned to a width, it will be X% of the parent's width.

vh and vw are viewport values. vh is the viewport height and vw is the viewport width. If I remember correctly, the viewport is the space in the window that is for displaying content. That excludes things like the url bar.

em is a fontsize value; however, it should work for width and height sizes. em refers to the current fontsize.

rem is a fontsize value that refers to the root's (or document's) font size.